# How many initial and discounted raffle tickets should I try to sell to earn $400 when the probability of selling discounted decreases per buyer?

Tags: probability, optimization

How many initial and discounted raffle tickets should I try to sell to profit $400?

The initial ticket costs `$10`  and each successive ticket costs `$3`.

$$ f(x) = 10 \\ f(y) = 3 $$

The probability of a person buying a $10 ticket is `0.3`.
The probability of any additional purchases start at a probability of `0.5`, and decrease by 0.1 with each following purchase.
$$ P(x) = 0.3 \\ P(y{\tiny 0}) = 0.5 \\ P(y{\tiny n}) = P(y{\tiny n-1})  -0.1 $$

Initially, I started off trying to maximize `10x+3y ≥ 400` to find how many tickets I should sell of each.
$$ 10x+3y =400$$

I realized that the real situation involved probability, so I added in the chance of buying an additional discounted ticket. I want to know how many initial and additional tickets can be expected to sell to hit the goal.

How should I approach this problem? And how can I better express this mathematically?

Answer (score 0):

You should start by computing the expected revenue from each person that you approach.  With probability $0.7$ you get nothing.  With probability $0.3 \cdot (1-0.5)$ you get $\$10$ because they buy only one ticket where the first factor is buying the first ticket and the second is not buying the second ticket, which is why I wrote it that way.  Compute the chance of each possible amount of revenue and use that to get the expected value.  Then divide that value into $\$400$

Comment: I calculated as so: `P(x) U P(y0) = 0.3 • (1-05) = 0.15`, `P(x) U P(y0) U P(y1) = 0.3 • 0.5 • (1-0.4) = 0.09`, so on until `P(x) U P(y0) U P(y1) U P(y2) U P(y3) U P(y4) U P(y5)  =  0.3 • 0.6 •  0.5 •  0.4 •  0.3 • 0.2 • (1-0.1) = 0.00324`. That's the probability of selling all of the tickets. But if I take it a step further and add P(6) where the probability of selling is 0 , the probability becomes 0.00036.  `0.3 • 0.6 •  0.5 •  0.4 •  0.3 • 0.2 • 0.1  • (1-0) = 0.00036`... How is these two probabilities different when they appear to me to ask the same question?

Comment: You are confusing yourself a few ways.  What is $P(y0)$?  In the first it is the chance you do not sell the second ticket, but it should be $\cap$ instead of $\cup$.  Later it is the chance you sold the second ticket.  Where does the $0.6$ come from?  Your sequence starts with $0.5$ as the chance to sell the second ticket given that you sold the first.  The $(1- )$ term is supposed to be the chance you don't sell the next ticket so you stop at the current one.